# Converting a Linear Fractional Transformation as a Hyperbola

Tags: linear-fractional-transformation

I'm trying to show algebraically that a Linear Fractional Transformation of the form
$$f(x)=\frac{(ax+b)}{(cx+d)}$$ can be written as hyperbolas of the form 
$$(x-h)(y-k)=m$$
I started by expanding the hyperbola equation to get
$$xy-hy-kx+hk=m$$
and then manipulated the LFT equation into
$$cxy-ax+d=b$$
This looks promising because all I need is another y term in the LFT equation and I can divide all constants by c and I will have something in the same form as the hyperbola equation but I have no clue how to get an extra y term.

The other consideration I had was to set h=0. If I did this I would be able to get the hyperbola equation into the form 
$$xy-kx=m$$
and the LFT into the form
$$cxy-ax=b-d$$
Is there a different way to show they are same without having to set h=0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$cxy-ax+d=b$$ should be $$cxy-ax+dy=b$$

$$c^2xy-acx+cdy=bc$$

$$ (cx+d)(cy-a) + ad = bc $$

$$ (cx+d)(cy-a)  = bc - ad $$

Comment: Thank you. Such a silly algebra mistake!